# Is it impossible to know if the de-authentication packet has been sent to the victim using Wireshark and mdk3?

Tags: linux, wifi, penetration-test, wireless, wireshark

I want to know if the clients get disconnected or not without checking there devices while I am outside the network. Is it impossible with WireShark?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not impossible. Wireless NIC in monitor mode capture also MGMT frames. If authentication request / association request follow de-auth frames then client got disconnected, but you can never be sure if you heard all frames.

Comment: which filter do i use to see the request  in WireShark

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to buy an awus alpha card, set it on monitor mode via a standard tool like airmon-ng and then rely on tool like wireshark to watch for unusual volume of deauth frames. The folder should be 
(wlan.fc.type == 0)&&(wlan.fc.type_subtype == 0x0c)
Or something similar